# Login Error when authenticating with Kerberos

Tags: active-directory, websphere, kerberos, spnego, gssapi

We are facing an interesting problem. Users login to application with Kerberos authentication. Few times they are successful, but suddenly they face lockout for their user login information and they see the error below on their screen

```
Login error: com.ibm.security.krb5.KrbException, status code: 24
    message: Pre-authentication information was invalid
Stack Trace : 
javax.security.auth.login.FailedLoginException: Login error: com.ibm.security.krb5.KrbException, status code: 24
    message: Pre-authentication information was invalid
    at com.ibm.security.jgss.i18n.I18NException.throwFailedLoginException(I18NException.java:33)
    at com.ibm.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule.a(Krb5LoginModule.java:457)
    at com.ibm.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule.b(Krb5LoginModule.java:377)
    at com.ibm.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule.login(Krb5LoginModule.java:200)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor36.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:56)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:620)
    at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.invoke(LoginContext.java:781)
    at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.access$000(LoginContext.java:215)
    at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext$4.run(LoginContext.java:706)
    at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext$4.run(LoginContext.java:704)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:452)
```

When we restart websphere application servers, everything works for the same users till they face the issue again. We have tried to check logs and change keytab file, but nothing has worked. Has anyone face this issue?

Comment: I've noted you've already validated everything was working fine in your setup scenario here -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42498111/spnego-authentication-issue-with-password  -  but *message: Pre-authentication information was invalid* means a bad password was sent.  I thought you said you have only one AD domain controller.  But this error suggests a possibility there might be another AD domain controller somewhere the users are hitting which may be out of synch with the first one.   What is the result when you run the command:  *netdom query fsmo*

Comment: I would also add these tags to this question:  *SPNEGO* and *GSSAPI*

Comment: The other is a different environment which i was configuring to recreate the issue I am facing in this question. Considering the issue occurs occasionally, it is very hard to recreate.

Comment: Disregard my last question. You could have an AD replication issue.  Are your users experiencing password issues generally, in other areas of the network?   Run this command on any of your AD domain controllers:  *dcdiag /v* and let us know if there are any errors shown in the result

Comment: How often does the problem occur for users?  All of the time?  Intermittently?  Happening to the same users, or to different users?  Any pattern that can be discerned?  What was the last change before the problem started happening, and when did it start?

Comment: @T-Heron - This problem is happening in production environment, to different users at different time. It generally happens when there are lot of users accessing the system. The last change before the problem started happening, was the Websphere upgrade to 8.5.5. Current temporary solution is to restart websphere application server and the problem goes away for sometime.

Comment: I have asked for dcdiag /v, i have yet to get feedback about that.

Answer (score 5):

It might be linked to a time (NTP) issue.

Kerberos preauthentification uses a timestamp as far as I know (to generate one-time-passwords), so I bet an NTP issue could cause that kind of problems.

Also, credentials not being destroyed could lead in such problems I suppose (e;g users not logged off correctly)

Check that all your servers (appservers where the app is running, as well as the Kerberos KDC) are synchronized with an NTP server and have the exact same time.

Comment: This was my exact first answer to this particular question when I came across the issue. I will have to get back to you on this.

Comment: Just stumbled upon this question again.  Did it wind up being a time sync problem?